# How to compute two Dimensional SNR

Tags: matlab, snr

[image]

The signal is the white dot or it is a point target. and I have to find the SNR of this image/point target. As i increase noise in thie image, black back ground shows some disturbance. AnHow should i approach this problem. I have to do it in matlab code.

Answer (score 1):

Basically I am working on the compressed response(poin target) of an image. Here in image i have a point target(white bright dot) and in zoom your can see its RGB cells. I want to compute 2 Dimensional SNR of point target. Point target is the signal and rest of it is noise.
This processed image has an array of (512x1024)rows*coulums= 524288 pixels
My approach is follow the basic formula SNR= 10log(Psignal/Pnoise)
The point target (white bright point) has a main lobe(compressed response) (bump)
The rest are side lobes.
##Power_signal= Main_loob Energy/pixels covered by point target##Power_noise= Rest side lobes/(Total Pixels - pixels of point target)##
I am working on this approach and not completed yet...
I need guidance on 2D SNR:

1. Is my approach correct
   2)Do we consider back ground as noise or not
   3)Any other methods that will make the problem easy to solve

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are several definition. However, traditionally, SNR computations require a reference image $I(m,n)$ (here the white dot on the black background, and a disturbed image  $I_d(m,n)$. The SNR is simply a logarithmic measure of the ratio of the energy of the reference with the energy of the "disturbance", here noise:

$$ \textrm{SNR} = 10\log \frac{\sum_{m,n}|I(m,n)|^2}{\sum_{m,n}|I(m,n)-I_d(m,n)|^2} $$

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir.. I would to like to ask relavant to your answer..In ideal condition when there is no noise, do we consider background as noise... How to calculate SNR then....Again Thanks for your considerate reply... Also it would be nice if you see my SNR approach in secend answer. Whether it is fine or not

Comment: It is possible to compute a so-called signal-to-background ratio. This however often requires either to 1) have a estimate of a background (from passive measurements) or to 2) estimate/separate a background from the signal at hand